# How to display content on left side of form

Tags: css

I am trying to display the `<aside class="side-buttons">` on the left side of the form `ytengine-form` but its not working - link is [here](http://www.servergreek.com/).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

this could be a solution put the form(ytengine-form) and the aside tag inside a div, give it a class name(.form-wrapper for example or any other name you prefer) then apply the following css rules to it

```
.form-wrapper{
 width:65%;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

then instead of floating each image inside the aside tag to the left float the div(.side-buttons) to the left, then set the display property to the images inside of it to block, this will allow each image to display one on top of the other. example:

```
.side-buttons{
    float:left;
}

.side-buttons img {
    width: 70px;
    height: auto;
    background:#FFFFF;
    padding : 10px;
    display:block;
}
```

Note: i used width:65% to keep the images inside the aside tag close to the form. then i used margin:0 auto to center them on the screen.